# Tips on getting the notes of a song through earing (guitar)

Tags: guitar

The question is clear, i find quite hard to reproduce/find a songs guitar note.
Sometimes it doesnt resemble the music note. I play mostly by tabs.
This applies to eletric guitar and fingerstyle pieces. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it doesn't sound like the note, it isn't the note.

Comment: I think the question would be more clear if it were phrased as a question with a question mark at the end. What is the actual question?